# Нужна ли запятая перед "снова"?

Tags: запятые

"У меня заняло столько времени снова добраться сюда..." Нужна ли здесь запятая перед "снова"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. В этом предложении "добраться" — это подлежащее, "заняло столько времени" — сказуемое. Подлежащее и сказуемое не отделяются друг от друга запятыми.

Comment: Поинтересуйтесь, что скрывается под опцией «Закрыть». Это полезно знать.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, эта опция есть только у участников с определенным рейтингом. У меня пока нет.

Comment: Возможно. Своими словами: политика сайта — не выполнять домашних заданий. Их нетрудно узнать, они стереотипны.

Comment: Видимо, мне нужно еще набраться опыта, чтобы начать узнавать домашние задания.

Comment: Закрывают не поэтому (уже 3 голоса из 5), а из-за того, что элементарно. Такие вопросы здесь не любят, хотя они не запрещены. А на дз здесь ничего не намекает. Вот о рейтинге: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: Я пока не могу закрывать, но могла бы нажать на "тревогу" - только в этом вопросе не за что. Оно, может быть, и элементарно, но поиск ответа на такой вопрос в гугле неочевиден: как сформулировать запрос, если не знаешь, в чем проблема?